# passing text variable using shell_exec

Tags: php

I try to passing text using shell_exec.

```
$message="I go to school";

shell_exec("nohup php -q sendmail.php $picture $message");
```

but I get only the one word of message when I user argv[2].
what the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You must add " for text

```
shell_exec("nohup php -q sendmail.php $picture \"$message\"");
```

Comment: It is hard to believe ;) Show me your code after changes, make sure you are running proper script and show code how you get this data